# Is 75 minutes enough to transfer at Schiphol airport?

Tags: short-connections, ams

I'm planning to travel from Abu Dhabi to Zurich via AMS.
The connection time is 1 hour 15 minutes. Within that time I need to get transferred including security and passport control. Is that enough time?

Answer (score 4):

You'll clear EU customs and immigration in Amsterdam, since that's where you're entering the Schengen area.  This sounds tight to me, especially if you have to re-clear security afterwards (which is a possibility).

If the trip is on one ticket, the airline selling you the ticket will have a responsibility to accommodate you if you miss your connection, but personally, I'd rather have a longer connection booked, to minimize stress and maximize the chances of making your flight.